# The id provided does not exist - razorpay in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am implementing Razorpay using PHP. I have followed all the steps as instructed in the documentation. The steps seems pretty straightforward and I have generated the test key from their website as required. I get the following error:

> The id provided does not exist

Here is my code (index.php):

```
<?php
$key = 'rzp_test_9JJVqHZjxnxyF1';
?>
</head>
<form action="index.html" method="POST">
<script
src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
data-key="<?php echo $key;?>" 
data-amount="100" 
data-currency="INR"
data-order_id="order_CgmcjRh9ti2lP7"
data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
data-name="Example"
data-description="test"
data-image="https://example.com/your_logo.jpg"
data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
data-prefill.email="gaurav.kumar@example.com"
data-theme.color="#F37254"
></script>

<input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data-order_id` value is a dummy order_id from documentation. You have to create order_id yourself by using their [php package](https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-php/releases/)

```
include '/razorpay-php/Razorpay.php'; //include library

use Razorpay\Api\Api;

$api= new Api($api_key, $api_secret);

$order  = $api->order->create([
    'receipt'         => $transaction_id, // generate your own transaction id
    'amount'          => $amount, // amount in the smallest currency unit
    'currency'        => 'INR',
    'payment_capture' =>  '1' 
  ]);
```

`$order->id` will give you the order_id created in above process.